# How to synchronize the data received from Apache IoTDB to be real-time when using pipe in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am now using version 1.2.2 of Apache IoTDB. After setting data server A being synchronized to server B, server B's data can be successfully written when using `start pipe`, but there will be no change when I execute query statement thereafter. Only after executing flush for server A, the data in server B will be written to the disk and be able to query. I want to know how to set up the pipe to let the data received in server B to be in real-time? The following are my pipe settings now:
`create pipe A2B
WITH EXTRACTOR (

```
'extractor'= 'iotdb-extractor',
'extractor.realtime.enable' = 'true', 
'extractor.history.enable' = 'false', 
'extractor.realtime.mode'='stream'
```

)
with connector (

```
'connector'='iotdb-thrift-connector',
'connector.ip'='iotdb',
'connector.port'='6667'
```

)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the open-source version of Apache IoTDB, it should only support file-level synchronization. Operation-level data synchronization (which improves real-time characteristics) and hybrid synchronization (combining two ways) can be supported in enterprise version.